# Remove tags that created after page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have small application:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdf6/4/

But with click on delete, tags that created after page load doesnt remove.
Is there any way to remove tags that created after page load?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hummm... you don't have any action on remove... What do you want ? remove added element with jQuery, or reload the page ?

Comment: I think everyone should stop just quickly answering `.live()` for these types of questions. It is not a best practice, and `.delegate()` should be used instead in MOST cases. And we should suggest best practices here, not hunting rep.

Comment: See @Mark's answer for a more efficient solution than using `live()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** - **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Wyrka/)**.

```
$('.sp').live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

As you're creating your elements dynamically, using `click()` isn't enough - that only assigns a click handler to all the `.sp` elements that exist at the time `click()` is called.

[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), on the other hand, is used to:

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

So any new elements added dynamically with a class of `sp` will have that handler attached to them.

**EDIT:** Actually, as a couple of people have pointed out, while `live()` will do what you need, the most efficient function to use in this instance would be [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which is used to:

> Attach a handler to one or more events
>   for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based
>   on a specific set of root elements.

I won't steal glory by posting a code sample - see @Mark's answer, which should be accepted instead of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

`.delegate()` would be the best option since the items all share a common parent.

```
$('#theList').delegate(".sp", "click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Bwdf6/7/)**

Comment: +1 Mark, I wasn't aware that delegate would be more efficient in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is why [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is 'invented'.

Change:

```
$('.sp').click (function() {
```

with:

```
$('.sp').live('click', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.live()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdf6/5/